# Showing Old Value in JTable in swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

In this code block I'm getting old values after clicking inside scroll pane, however new values also disappear at first on fetching but they slowly disappear and old values appear in that place.

I tried a few combinations but was't able to achieve the results as expected. Also during variable declaration I made all the variables as non-static except the frame which I suppose is not relevant and recommended  and I'm also embedding the components on frame itself.

```
//THE TABLE
table = new JTable();
//THE COLUMN

String[] columns = new String[] {
    "Serial No", "BundleId", "Bundle Count", "Record Count","Status","Date"
};
 //THE ROW

Object[][] data = dc.Success(date,afterDate);  
final Class[] columnClass = new Class[] {
        Boolean.class,String.class, String.class, String.class,String.class,String.class };

 //create table model with data
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
    {
        return columnClass[columnIndex];
    }


    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return "";
    }
};

// JTable table = new JTable(model);

table.setModel(model);

//add the table to the frame
//ADD SCROLLPANE
scroll.setBounds(70, 80, 600, 400);
scroll.setViewportView(table);
frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
// this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
// table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(320, 160));
TableColumn tc = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(BOOLEAN_COL);
tc.setHeaderRenderer(new SelectAllHeader(table, BOOLEAN_COL));
this.setTitle("Table Example");
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
this.pack();
this.setVisible(true);
table.repaint();
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I have added an answer about updating a `JTable` in a general case. However, if you are after something else pose an MCVE like Andrew said :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to notify your JTable about changes of your data, use something similar to [`tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged--).

There are other methods that can be used for updating specific ranges of data. [`tableModel.fireTableRowsUpdated​(firstRow, lastRow)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsUpdated-int-int-) might be of particular use to you. This is because you suggest you only update a single row when that row is clicked on. If that is not the case, stick to [`tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged--).

From your comments, I notice you are trying to fire a data change event and then changing your whole model anyway. This is not required and could actually be the source of your issues if your model is holding the old values.

Instead you should change the `DataVector` of the current model. To change the data on a single row you could use something like the following extract of code. There is a full example below the extract.

```
//Get your row's values from your database
//I'll use random values for this purpose
int col1Val = getRand(0, 9);
int col2Val = getRand(0, 9);

//Put the values in an object vector
Vector<Object> rowVals = new Vector<>();
rowVals.addElement(col1Val);
rowVals.addElement(col2Val);

//Set the object vector
model.getDataVector().setElementAt(rowVals, table.getSelectedRow());

//Notify the table the row has changed
model.fireTableRowsUpdated(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedRow());
```

Full example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTableExample extends JFrame {
    private static final String windowName = "JTable Example";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 362702020844358278L;

    private JPanel tablePanel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPanel;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    private JTableExample() {
        super(windowName);
        SetUp();
    }

    private void SetUp() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SetUpJTable();
        SetUpJPanel();

        add(tablePanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void SetUpJPanel() {
        tablePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        tablePanel.add(scrollPanel);
    }

    private void SetUpJTable() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
            "Something", "Something Else"
        };

        String[][] data = new String[][] {
            {"1", "2"},
            {"3", "3"}
        };

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -3895234084030399437L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
            {
                return false;
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(model);

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //Get your row's values from your database
                //I'll use random values for this purpose
                int col1Val = getRand(0, 9);
                int col2Val = getRand(0, 9);

                //Put the values in an object vector
                Vector<Object> rowVals = new Vector<>();
                rowVals.addElement(col1Val);
                rowVals.addElement(col2Val);

                //Set the object vector
                model.getDataVector().setElementAt(rowVals, table.getSelectedRow());

                //Notify the table the row has changed
                model.fireTableRowsUpdated(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedRow());
            }
        });

        scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    private static int getRand(int min, int max) {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new JTableExample());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan I tried the same however it's still showing me the same phenomenon while getting the value from the database

Comment: model.fire tableData changed();table.setModel(model);

Comment: Here I m getting the new value but it's getting overridden by old value on mouseclick inside a scrollpane

Comment: @RatanSingh Good morning, I have updated my answer. Essentially, I do not think you need to use `table.setModel(...)`. I have shown a way to only set the value of a single row if you are updating it on click as you described

Comment: Actually Dan I m updating my data on click of a submit button and from there the value is getting updated.....

Comment: @RatanSingh Ah my bad. Just call [model.setDataVector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setDataVector-java.lang.Object:A:A-java.lang.Object:A-) followed by fireTableDataChanged when you click your button